# How do you create a game with a working betting feature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, integer, blackjack

I'm new to Python and coding in general. I was wondering someone could have a look at what I need to change...

```
    # Amount of chips player has

    starting_chips = 1000

    print('Player 1 has {}\n'.format(starting_chips))

    # Amount of chips player wants to bet
    try:
        placed_bet = int(input('Place your bet: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue
    print('')

    if placed_bet > starting_chips:
        print("You don't have enough funds")
        continue
    else:
        break

# A deduction from players total chips of the total bet
total_chips = (starting_chips - placed_bet)

losing_total = (starting_chips - placed_bet)

print('You now have: {}\n'.format(total_chips))

#If the player wins the hand
total_chips = ((placed_bet * 2) + starting_chips)
```

link to the whole code here --> https://github.com/Joeet33/CardGame

Comment: Please write more about the problem in the description. I'm not sure what it is that you need help changing. What is the problem that is happening, or that you are trying to solve? (What is missing?)

Comment: Hi Mike, the issue is once I have been through the loop I want my "starting_chips" to change as well. E.g. say I choose to bet "500". I win against the dealer, so I now have "1500". However when I go through the loop again it resets back to the value 1000. If you need me to explain more just say, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `starting_chips` why not just use `total_chips` and initialize it before the while loop? Ultimately the variable you are modifying is "how many chips does the player have". `starting_chips` could be used as a constant provided at the top of the script `STARTING_CHIPS = 1000` then later having `total_chips = STARTING_CHIPS` located just above your while loop.

Ultimately each time the while loop returns to the top, it resets all the values back to your original 1000.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's helped a lot!

Comment: @JoeEllul-Turner good to hear. If this is the answer you are looking for select the checkmark next to the arrows. It selects it as the answer! Glad to help.